# WebView is not able to show Website

Tags: android, webview

Here is my code:

XML

```
   <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

MainActivity.java excerpt

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

This should show the google page upon starting the app. However every time I run this, I get an error of "Webpage not available, The webpage might be temporarily down or it may have moved to a new web address, etc"

Any ideas?

Comment: omg. I forgot the internet permission. Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are connected to internet and you have following permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Android edition seems to be old you must use a modern one or use your mobile phone.
It will work well when will you use this app on your mobile phone

Comment: He already found a solution 2 years ago (missing permission in manifest). Please focus on a more current question next time